# Divide and update Text Area in JAVAFX at runtime

Tags: javafx-2

My application is developed using JavaFX. I send a command from the JavaFX client to a jar file on a solaris machine and take the output of that jar file and display it on text area in my JavaFX application using JSCH.  Originally, there was only one thread in the jar file present on the solaris machine, so all output was sequential and there was no confusion.  But now i have implemented multithreading in the JAR file present on Solaris AND this caused an issue as below:

I want To display the output of each thread differently in the text area.  I want to divide the text area into parts equal to the number of threads used in the solaris machines jar file. I have found the way send the number of threads from solaris to my JavaFX application.

How can I divide the text area into parts?

---

Below is the code where i am printing output of a thread in the text area:

```
while ((jarOutput = reader.readLine()) != null) {
  this.logger.info("Status Update = " + jarOutput);

  bw.write(jarOutput);
  bw.newLine();
  bw.flush();
  outputFromUnix.append(jarOutput).append("\n");

  // Display in activity log area in realtime.
  if (DeploymentTaskController.actLogTArea != null 
        && !taskName.equalsIgnoreCase(connectBundle)) {
    final String outputStr = outputFromUnix.toString();
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
        DeploymentTaskController.actLogTArea.setText(outputStr);
        DeploymentTaskController.actLogTArea.end();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems, you will have to create a text area per each thread (many text areas), or you can use text flow from JFX8, where you can make each line of text in a different way (different color for instance), and use only one textFlow.

Comment: Hi Alexander...see i am already having one text area in which some text will be printed first and after that i want to print thread wise text.So here i am having two option either provide the link from client text area to new text area and update the threads log there or provide the link to new stage and update the thread logs there.Can anybody gives the example of doing this?

Comment: Can anybody provide the example for this?